# What does the -PIPE flag do in a kill command

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh, kill-process

A KornShell (ksh) script (*scriptC.ksh*) is called indirectly by *scriptA.ksh* (*scriptA.ksh* calls *scriptB.ksh* which calls *scriptC.ksh*).

***scriptC.ksh:***

```
kill -PIPE ${PPID}
```

What does the `-PIPE` flag do here? If the -PIPE flag is used in *scriptC.ksh* then this is the output:

***scriptA Output:***

```
@:/tmp #ksh sciprtA.ksh
sciprtA.ksh[100]: 343434 Terminated
Terminated
```

If `-PIPE` is removed then this is the terminal output for *scriptC.ksh* exits.:

***scriptC.ksh:***

```
kill ${PPID}
```

***scriptA Output:***

```
@:/tmp #ksh sciprtA.ksh
Terminated
```

Any insight regarding this?

Comment: Try `man ksh` and look for the section describing the `kill` builtin command.

Comment: @twalberg No luck on the machine's local man pages...

Answer (score 5):

### Background

`kill -PIPE` is telling the process that the thing it's writing to has exited, so it should exit too.

For example:

```
$ grep something file | more
```

When the `more` process stops reading, `grep` will buffer up a bit more output, but then will be paused by the kernel until `more` starts reading again (the size of the buffer is determined by the kernel).

Suppose there are a bazillion matches in the file; `grep` could keep on printing lines until the cows come home, on demand (only a few lines will get buffered, then `more` reads them, and when the buffer is depleted, `grep` will be woken up again to produce a bit more output).

But, if `more` exits early (the user has got bored reading the lines), there's no point for `grep` to keep spitting out stuff. Instead it will be sent `SIGPIPE` to say, "your output pipe has gone away". The default action on `SIGPIPE` is to terminate.

So, `SIGPIPE` is a weird quirk of Unix: on most platforms, if you're writing to a file and there's an error, you get an error return code produced and it's just like any other failure (that is, on Windows for instance, errors for `WriteFile` are indicated by the return code for the function, just like those for `DeleteFile` or any other Win32 function). Unix is unique, in that errors for `write` are handled by applications in a completely different way to errors for any other system call, through an out-of-band mechanism (signal handler). That's because pipelines are at the heart of the Unix command-line philosophy, so it's expected whenever you're writing to any pipe that you'd want special behaviour when the consumer of your stream goes away!

### In your example

In your script, you're explicitly telling a process to terminate, and optionally do any cleanup it would expect to do if it were in a pipeline. Unfortunately, you haven't given us enough context to guess why your script is written that way (actually including the relevant portions of your scripts might explain the mystery). In the example with `grep` above though, sending `SIGPIPE` to `grep` would be a way of causing `more` to exit gracefully (if `grep` exits with `SIGTERM`, the parent shell might be expected to report a fiercer error, depending on how its implementation monitors the pipeline).

Comment: +1, nice answer. Would this also apply to when disk is full and something like `echo "msg" | mail ...` fails? (Do you have a source for SIG info (besides man -s? signals(.h) ?)

Comment: Disk full is a different sort of write error to a pipe error - it only exists for regular files, and pipe errors are just for pipes! The thing with pipes is there for situations with huge amounts of data, like a grep through / that might take hours, so it's important to kill it as soon as the next process in its pipeline has gone.